# Internet explorer gradients coming out blue

Tags: internet-explorer, css

A few elements of my webpage are rendering blue in IE 8 for some reason, i thought it was due to me using the rgba styling instead of rgb, but i removed it and still renders blue.
Works perfect on every other browser including mobile ones.
Heres the site:

http://www.morzi.com/constantine

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Turns up blue in IE9 and FF too? Which elements are you reffering too?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, was using filter instead of -ms-filter

Comment: pufffffffff. Another IE kick in the back

Comment: have you considered using CSS3Pie instead of hacking around with IE's filters? It'll make life a lot easier for you.